# How to fix: ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastobo

Tags: python, pip, pyproject.toml, rustup

I am trying to install this library nxontology using the command below:

`pip install nxontology`

It is giving me the error below:

```
 Building wheel for fastobo (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

 Building wheel for fastobo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'src\py\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'src\py\header\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'src\py\instance\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'src\py\term\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      package init file 'src\py\typedef\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      running build_rust
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\cargo
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\rustup
      downloading rustup.sh install script
      installing Rust compiler to build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastobo
Failed to build fastobo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fastobo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I saw some answers to similar errors but none of them worked for me.

pip version: pip 22.1.1 from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

Project python interpreter: Python 3.9.

I would really appreciate if you have any idea how to fix this.

Comment: Well it's been 11 months and I forgot I asked this question here. Since I was using a conda environment the problem was that I was calling pip from a normal command prompt. The solution for me was to open the anaconda prompt, activate my conda environment that I used in the project, go to my project directory and install pip there. After that I was able to install libraries using pip without any problem (using the anaconda prompt for that as well).